# Jquery multiple conditional validation

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery script which is used to check conditional statement based on certain values.

```js
function is_numeric(val) {
  status = $.isNumeric(val);
  console.log("Our numeric status => " + status);
  if (status) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
function hasValue(elem) {
  return $(elem).filter(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).length > 0;
}
function validate_KRA_Pin() {
  var nationality = $(".nationality").val();
  console.log("Nationality => " + nationality);
  if (nationality == '110') {
    var validate_DoB = hasValue(".Date_of_Birth");
    if (validate_DoB) {
      var client_age = calculate_age();
      if (client_age >= 18) {
        $(".KRA_Pin_Error").show();
        $(".kra_pin_div").show();
        var pin_no = hasValue(".pin_no");
        if (pin_no) {
          var kra_pin_val = $(".pin_no").val();
          var first_char = (kra_pin_val.charAt(0));
          var second_char = is_numeric(kra_pin_val.charAt(1));
          var third_char = is_numeric(kra_pin_val.charAt(2));
          var fourth_char = is_numeric(kra_pin_val.charAt(3));
          var fifth_char = is_numeric(kra_pin_val.charAt(4));
          var sixth_char = is_numeric(kra_pin_val.charAt(5));
          var seventh_char = is_numeric(kra_pin_val.charAt(6));
          var eigth_char = is_numeric(kra_pin_val.charAt(7));
          var ninth_char = is_numeric(kra_pin_val.charAt(8));
          var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
          var last_char = kra_pin_val.slice(-1);
          if ((kra_pin_val.length == 11) && (second_char == true) && (third_char == true) && (fourth_char == true) && (fifth_char == true) && (sixth_char == true) && (seventh_char == true) && (eigth_char == true) && (ninth_char == true)) {
            console.log("TRUE CONDITIONS MET....");
            if (first_char.match(letters) && last_char.match(letters)) {
              $(".KRA_Pin_Error").hide();
              return true;
            } else {
              $(".KRA_Pin_Error").show();
              return false;
            }
          } else {
            $(".KRA_Pin_Error").show();
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        $(".KRA_Pin_Error").hide();
        $(".kra_pin_div").hide();
        return true;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The script is supposed to meet the following conditions :

1. It should be 11 characters
2. The first character and last characters should be letters
3. The middle characters should be numbers
4. Example : A123456789D

The following validation works :

```
if ((kra_pin_val.length == 11){
  console.log("TRUE CONDITIONS MET....");
}
```

However if I do the following, it fails :

```js
if ((kra_pin_val.length == 11) && (second_char == true) && (third_char == true) && (fourth_char == true) && (fifth_char == true) && (sixth_char == true) && (seventh_char == true) && (eigth_char == true) && (ninth_char == true)) {
  console.log("TRUE CONDITIONS MET....");


  if (first_char.match(letters) && last_char.match(letters)) {
    $(".KRA_Pin_Error").hide();
    return true;

  } else {
    $(".KRA_Pin_Error").show();
    return false;
  }
}
```

How can I validate the  following values : 
A123456789P: This is true and A123456TR9D: This is false

Comment: With the power of regular expressions! `if (/^[A-Z]\d{9}[A-Z]$/.test(kra_pin_val)) { ... }`. `^[A-Z]` will search for an uppercase letter in first position, `\d{9}` will search for 9 numbers, `[A-Z]$` will search for an uppercase letter in last position.

Comment: Just a hint: a Regex will do exactly what you want in one single line. Here's a link that should help you start: [https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)

Comment: Also please `$(".KRA_Pin_Error").toggle(!valid);`